# Select query with join -syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT SampleSheet.Id,SampleSheet.Sample_Complete,SampleSheet.SampleName,"
                + "count(Job.sampleId) AS NumberOfSamples FROM (SampleSheet "
                + "LEFT JOIN Job ON SampleSheet.Id = Job.sampleId) "
                + "WHERE SampleSheet.Sample_Complete=?"
                + "GROUP BY SampleSheet.Id
```

Can anynone please tell me whats wrong in this query.  I am getting syntax error.

It works Fine if I dont use the Where Condition. But I need to get the rows for the ones where the sample is complete.

```
SELECT SampleSheet.Id,SampleSheet.Sample_Complete,SampleSheet.SampleName,count(Job.sampleId) AS NumberOfSamples FROM (SampleSheet LEFT JOIN Job ON SampleSheet.Id = Job.sampleId) GROUP BY SampleSheet.Id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of suggestions. It seems to be space issue after `WHERE` clause

```
            + "WHERE SampleSheet.Sample_Complete=?"
            + "GROUP BY SampleSheet.Id
```

instead

```
            + "WHERE SampleSheet.Sample_Complete=? "
            + "GROUP BY SampleSheet.Id
```

You could also remove `(` just after `FROM` and obviously `)` as well. It is not required.

```
 FROM (SampleSheet "
            + "LEFT JOIN Job ON SampleSheet.Id = Job.sampleId) "
```